# Azure WebJob with TimerTrigger just firing 5 times

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I recently created an Azure WebJob which is intended to be executed every 5 minutes, forever. Thing comes when I can see it just gets executed every 5 minutes but just 5 times:

> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] The next 5 occurrences of the schedule will be: *
> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] 8/25/2020 2:46:51 PM *
> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] 8/25/2020 2:51:51 PM *
> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] 8/25/2020 2:56:51 PM *
> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] 8/25/2020 3:01:51 PM *
> [08/25/2020 12:41:51 > 2e704f: INFO] 8/25/2020 3:06:51 PM

On my Azure AppService => WebJobs panel I can see the last time it got executed was 17 hours ago, which confirms this just got fired those shown scheduled times.

My `webjob-publish-settings.json` is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "Inbox",
  "runMode": "Scheduled"  
}
```

My `Functions.cs` contains a single async method with this firm:

```
public async static Task SomethingAsync([TimerTrigger("00:05:00", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = true)] TimerInfo timer)
```

And my `Program.cs` sets `JobHostConfiguration` to call the `UseTimers()` method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }
    config.UseTimers();
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.Start();
}
```

I've already tried using a CRON expresion instead the `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` expression already set with the same luck (kept the TimeSpan expression since it's easier to read) with the same result. Note I'm using the v2.3.0 version of the Azure WebJobs.

What am I exactly missing? Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: have you turned on the "always on" feature for you webjob?

Comment: @IvanYang I've just reviewed my AppService's config and it's set as "always on", yes.

Answer (score 0):

The root of my problem was a **bad interpretation of concepts**.

What I really needed was a WebJob to call my function every 5 minutes. I thought I needed a scheduled WebJob and looking at the console output and seeing the "scheduled ocurrences" made me think **they were being called when in fact they weren't**.

What was really happening was that my WebJob was getting started, launching the function (thanks to the `RunOnStartup = true`), it was identifying the specified `TimerTrigger` and then the JobHost ended.

What did I change? **Moved to continuous WebJob**.

1. Changed the `webjob-publish-settings.json`'s runMode to "Continuous"
2. Changed the `JobHost`'s method from `Call()` to `RunAndBlock()`
3. Set the TimerTrigger to 1 minute to perform the tryout.

Be careful about the third point, where I was originally intented to launch the function every 5 minutes and I remember suffering `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` errors since the CPU was idle for more than 120 seconds. That's another war I will probably fight later on.

So now I'm finally seing my Function called every minute:

> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:42:4 ...)     Success     41 seconds ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:41:4 ...)   Success     2 minutes ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:40:4 ...)   Success     3 minutes ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:39:4 ...)   Success     4 minutes ago (1 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:38:4 ...)   Success     5 minutes ago (1 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:37:4 ...)   Success     6 minutes ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:36:4 ...)   Success     7 minutes ago (1 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:35:4 ...)   Success     8 minutes ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:34:4 ...)   Success     9 minutes ago (2 s running time)
> Functions.SomethingAsync (08/26/2020 09:33:4 ...)   Success     10 minutes ago (1 s running time)